# Create SQL login to multiple instances at once

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, powershell

I have a AD group that needs to be added to multiple SQL instances, I am wondering is there a quicker way of adding this group at once rather than having to login to each server and creating a login in SQL?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download the awesome Powershell scripts from [dbatools](https://dbatools.io/download/) and use [New-DbaLogin](https://docs.dbatools.io/#New-DbaLogin) to add the new login.

Example:

`New-DbaLogin -SqlInstance sql1 -Login domain\user`

Comment: It doesn't work, I have downloaded the .zip from dbatools and I am trying to execute the command but keep receiving a error the term 'new-DbaLogin' is not recognised as the name of a cmdlet

Comment: @Vishal Read the [getting started](https://dbatools.io/getting-started/) page for information on how to import the module, and more.

Comment: I have downloaded the .zip, my PS version is 3 I extracted the folder in my C: but when I execute the command I receive the same error....I am fairly new to Powershell so any further help would be appreciated thank you

Comment: @Vishal - make sure you follow the instructions for _Method 4: Download the zip directly and manually import the module._ - https://dbatools.io/download/ - particularly the information about _Once you’ve extracted the folder, make sure you rename it from dbatools-master or dbatools-development to plain o’ dbatools and place it somewhere in $env:PSMODULEPATH_

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a [Central Management Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/administer-multiple-servers-using-central-management-servers?view=sql-server-2017). Once you've done that, you can apply the same script (`CREATE LOGIN [Your_AD_Group] FROM WINDOWS WITH ...`) to multiple SQL instances at the same time.